# Can iOS still launch an app in range of iBeacon in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ibeacon, uibackgroundmode

I have been searching for days now on this subject. I have seen a few posts but none of the implementations work, or, they mention deprecated methods, options or Libraries that are private. I find Apple docs to be the worst thing of all time and yet even in that debacle wall of text known as their docs I found a few references to launching a terminated application based on entering the range of an iBeacon.

What I need is to have the app be fully closed and terminated as though the user is completed and finished with it. Then I need to use the `UIBackgroundMode` for BLE services in `info.plist` for listening to the `didRangeBeacons` delegate method. It fires, so I know that much is working.

It's at this point that all implementations so far have failed. How on earth do you launch the app to even a backgrounded state from being in range of an iBeacon? I am beginning to think all you can do is trigger a local notification when in range...

Comment: There's a lot to be done in terms of checking whether your devices is enabled and permitted, handling errors when setting up, etc.  Please post what you've tried.

Comment: @danh my code has now changed to match `davidgyoung`'s answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Getting an app to auto-launch from a not-running state based on iBeacon detection is surprisingly easy with `CoreLocation` and iBeacon.**

In order for it to work a few pre-requisites must be met:

1. The app must have been manually launched once before.
2. The app must request and obtain "Always" location access from the user on first launch.
3. The app must register a `CLBeaconRegion` with `CLLocationManager` by calling `locationManager.startMonitoring(region: region)`, and set the `locationManager.delegate`.   Since you also want to range, you can simultaneously call `startRanging(beacons: beacons, region: region)`.  It is usually easiest to do this in your `AppDelegate.`
4. The phone must have location enabled and bluetooth turned on.

If you do all of the above correctly, then iOS CoreLocation will remember that your app has registered the `CLBeaconRegion` and auto launch your app on beacon detection.  Even if you reboot the phone, or kill your app from the task switcher it will do this.  After auto launching your app into the background, it will call the `didEnter(region: region)` callback on your delegate and then start calling the `didRange(beacons: beacons, region: region)` callback once per second for about 10 seconds, until the operating system will once again suspend your app.

There are lots of ways to make mistakes when testing so this doesn't work. But if you do everything right, this is pretty darn reliable.

**What you can't do** is bring the app to the foreground programmatically, because iOS does not allow this.  On iOS, a user must gesture to bring an app to the foreground -- this is nothing to do with beacons, but a long-standing rule in the design of the OS.   This is why many apps send a local notification while they are in this brief background state after detecting a beacon to give the user a way to bring the app to the foreground.

Comment: This is awesome you sound like the exact person I need to talk to. Ok, so I have everything you mentioned in place and it's working as far as launching the didEnter and didExit methods and I have a notification coming up when they hit those states so I know the app is sort-of running. Keeping in mind that I know you can't re-launch an app to the foreground, my question is... how do I get the app to re-launch itself to the background state? From the background I can launch my bluetooth service and thats the true goal here. I need this iBeacon to launch to background so I can pair with bluetooth

Comment: what I mean by "background" is the app being in the task switcher, not just open as a service.

Comment: What is described above will allow you to start a bluetooth service during the 10s of background running time.  Also, be aware that an app relaunched in the background won't show up in the task switcher if you had removed it from the task switcher since it was last in the foreground.  Just because you don't see it there doesn't mean it wasn't launched into the background.  Use the XCode's Windows -> Devices -> iPhone panel to watch the logs from your connected device, and use NSLog to log events you can see there when your app re-launches.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much for the help I'll give it a try and report back tomorrow

Comment: I made this the correct answer for now but I hope you'll still answer my questions tomorrow

Comment: Sure, just post a new question and link from comments if applicable.

Comment: Hopefully you can still help me out, I posted the next question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145680/ios-ibeacon-bluetooth-connectivity-when-app-is-dead-and-gone